# How to loop over the static data members of a class - using a variable for the class name?

Tags: php, class, static

In PHP, if I have a class with static member variables, such as:

```
class Foo
{
    public static $a = 0;
    public static $b = 1;
}
```

... and I have a string variable containing the name of the class:

```
$foo = 'Foo';
```

... how do I loop over the static data members of class `Foo` using the variable `$foo`?

Something like:

```
// Does not work
foreach ($foo AS $field => &$value) {
    // Desired:
    // Iteration 1: $field = 'a', $value = 0
    // Iteration 2: $field = 'b', $value = 1
}
```

As noted, the above code snippet does not work.

Is this possible?  If so, what is the syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: @GordonM - It is a duplicate - I didn't find that other question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$staticMembers = $class->getStaticProperties();

foreach($staticMembers as $field => &$value) {
```